# Python - pyad create user with a comma in their name

Tags: python, pyad

I'm trying to create a user using pyad, what I have working is:

```
    ou = pyad.adcontainer.ADContainer.from_dn('OU=Employees,DC=lan,DC=company,DC=com')
    name =  ("doe john")
    newUser = pyad.aduser.ADUser.create(name, ou, password="password")
```

However if I try and make the name to be `doe, john` (has a comma in it now):

```
    ou = pyad.adcontainer.ADContainer.from_dn('OU=Employees,DC=lan,DC=company,DC=com')
    name =  ("doe, john")
    newUser = pyad.aduser.ADUser.create(name, ou, password="password")
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- packages\pyad\adcontainer.py", line 38, in create_user
obj.SetInfo()
File "<COMObject <unknown>>", line 2, in SetInfo
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Active 
Directory', 'An invalid dn syntax has been specified.\r\n', None, 0, -2147016654), None)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "NamelyToAD.py", line 49, in <module>
newUser = pyad.aduser.ADUser.create(name, ou, password="Password1")
File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pyad\aduser.py", line 16, in create
optional_attributes=optional_attributes
File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pyad\adcontainer.py", line 47, in create_user
pyadutils.pass_up_com_exception(e)
File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pyad\pyadutils.py", line 58, in pass_up_com_exception
raise WIN32_ERRORS.get(info['error_num'], win32Exception)(error_info=info, additional_info=additional_info)
pyad.pyadexceptions.win32Exception: 0x80072032: An invalid dn syntax has been specified.
```

I don't know how to get around including the comma, I've tried escaping it and including a chr(44) as well, but nothing works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two character issues you have to handle:

1. The RDN (e.g. `cn=User Name`) of an LDAP object [must](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/11216.active-directory-requirements-for-creating-objects.aspx#All_Classes_of_Objects) have the following characters escaped with a backslash:
   `, \ # + < > ; " =`
2. The `sAMAccountName` [cannot contain](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/11216.active-directory-requirements-for-creating-objects.aspx#Objects_with_sAMAccountName_Attribute) any of the following characters:
   `" [ ] : ; | = + * ? < > / \ ,`

`pyad` will [by default](https://github.com/zakird/pyad/blob/60cfa39986722cae516f2c31750cd0f75a12f31b/pyad/adcontainer.py#L36) attempt to set the `sAMAccountName` attribute to the `name` argument passed to `ADUser.create()`, so, if a forbidden character is in `name`, it is necessary to supply your own `sAMAccountName` as an optional attribute.

In your example, you would have to do something like:

```
pyad.aduser.ADUser.create("Doe\, John", ou, password="Password123", 
    optional_attributes={'sAMAccountName':'jdoe'})
```